# jQuery plugin that fits in my design

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I know it is quite subjective, but I also want to take this opportunity to know which are the most known jQuery plugins to work with tables, specifically: Make the tables more "presentable" to the user, and event handling when selecting rows. I would also be good to allow selecting more than one row. That's it. Here is my page:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "plugins to work with tables." is very vague. Be more specific, please.

Comment: If you need something else just let me know

Comment: What is that you are intending to do?

Comment: Its a basic simulation of an Operating System

Comment: The one in the left is supposed to be the main memory, the other is a list of programs with their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to guess your question:

If you want to know what jquery grids are available, you can se the following anwer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/159591/426812

Particulary I have used jqGrid it enables to you use Jquery UI theme roller for fit the appereance with your design.